# VBA - Footers modifications - Unlink to previous

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that creates a new page with a different orientation, and with a different tabulation.

I have this code :

```
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
If Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
  MsgBox "OK"
Else
  Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait

  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
  Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = Not Selection.HeaderFooter. _
    LinkToPrevious

  Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
  Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops(CentimetersToPoints(18)).Position = _
    CentimetersToPoints(18.5)
  Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=CentimetersToPoints(9.5), _
      Alignment:=wdAlignTabCenter, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End If

Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Annexe1")
```

Unfortunately this changes the tabulations of the page just before.

Is there a way i can solve this ?
I have tried the GoTo function, with page, section,...but it doesn't do the trick.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always tricky when you work with `Selection` in VBA code - it doesn't always precisely mimic what happens when the user performs actions. This is especially an issue with Headers and Footers when `SeekView` is used.

The following works with `Range` objects (think of a Range like an invisible selection, but you can have many Ranges in your VBA code - there can be only one selection).

It starts off by assigning the current selection to a Range object, then goes on to insert the Section Break and compare the page orientation, just as you have.

If the page orientation needs to be changed, the new section's footer is assigned to a `Footer` object. Then the footer's `Range.ParagraphFormat` is assigned to a `ParagraphFormat` object*. Notice how these are then used to change the settings you have in your code. The big difference is, the code doesn't put any selection in the footer: everything is done directly. This is not only faster and more accurate, it also reduces screen "flicker".

At the end, the original Range (which has since moved beyond the original selection) is selected, since I assume you want to continue with text input at that point. If not, then you can remove this line.

```
Sub ChangePageOrientationAndTabs()
    Dim ftr As word.HeaderFooter
    Dim pf As word.ParagraphFormat
    Dim rngSel As word.Range

    Set rngSel = Selection.Range
    rngSel.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    If rngSel.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
        MsgBox "OK"
    Else
        rngSel.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
        Set ftr = ActiveDocument.Sections(rngSel.Sections(1).index).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        ftr.LinkToPrevious = False

        Set pf = ftr.Range.ParagraphFormat
        pf.TabStops.ClearAll
        pf.TabStops(CentimetersToPoints(18)).Position = _
          CentimetersToPoints(18.5)
        pf.TabStops.Add Position:=CentimetersToPoints(9.5), _
          Alignment:=wdAlignTabCenter, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces

    End If

    rngSel.Paragraphs(1).Range.style = ActiveDocument.styles("Annexe1")
    rngSel.Select
End Sub
```

*It's a puzzle to me why assigning the Footer.Range to a `Range` object works on the previous section's Footer, while Footer and ParagraphFormat are correct...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Unfortunately it seems to be exactly the same problem.
I have tried with another file and I still have the same issue...

Comment: Maybe it comes from the sections(1) term ?

Comment: That's very strange, but when I looked more closely, you are definitely correct. I've found and posted a workaround that avoids using the Range object for the Footer. Never seen this happen before! There does seem to be some connection to rngSel somehow being linked to its originating section, even if I assign text to it, then collapse it so that it's fully on the new page. But rngSel returns the right section Index, so I've used that to get the correct Footer...

Comment: Perfect it works. I am actually not sure to understand it all. But that's alright.

Comment: I had another question concerning this macro. Should I open another thread ? It's on how to include a vbCrLf after the "Annexe1" line and then define a new format.
Even though I include it after the rngSel.Select, it adds the vbCrLf before the "Annexe1" line.

Comment: See if this helps, otherwise a new Question with full information: Do a `rngSelect.InsertAfter vbCr` followed by `rngSelect.Collapse wdCollapseEnd`. (Note: do NOT use vbCrLf in Word!) Now the focus should be in the paragraph you added and Annexe1 will be applied to that.

Comment: You can ask about what you don't understand and I'll be happy to amend my Answer so that it's clear(er).